# How to postForObject list of object?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, jpa, resttemplate

I have a working example of posting only one object, but i dont know how to post a list of object. Here's how im trying to do this :

**Client**

```
protected List<EventStudent> doInBackground(Object... params) {
            RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
            template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
            EventStudent[] array = new EventStudent[event.size()];
            event.toArray(array);
            template.postForObject(URL.GET_EVENT_INFO ,array, EventStudent[].class);
            return event;
        }
```

this is how im trying to get them on server:

**Server**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/eventstudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<EventStudent> saveRemider(@RequestBody List<EventStudent>event) {
    return service.save(event);
}
```

But it won't work

Answer (score 1):

the problem is generic and type erasure for List , this would be equivalent of List< ? > in controller method.

Create a custom list class just to wrap List into List that can be handled by spring mvc

```
public class EventStudentList extends ArrayList<EventStudent> {
}
```

and use it as

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/eventstudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public List<EventStudent> saveRemider(@RequestBody EventStudentList  event) {
    return service.save(event);
}
```